# how to sort by 2 fields using lambda in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I would like to sort by one field, but if there's a tie, I want to be able to sort using another field using the function sorted with lambda:

In the example below. I am able to sort by age of my students. I would like to order by grade 'A' before 'B' in case there's a tie:

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('mike', 'A', 12)]
print(sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   )# sort by age
```

my result is:

```
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('mike', 'A', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

but I want to swap the orders of Mike and Jane.

Please, only solutions using sorted and lambda.

Comment: `lambda s:(s[2], s[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tuple containing the items of priority in the sort `key`:

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('mike', 'A', 12)]
new_tuples = sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda data:(data[-1], data[1]))
```

Output:

```
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('mike', 'A', 12), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the sorting key by the value of `ord(student[1])`:

```
print(sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2]+ord(student[1])))
```

It prints out:

```
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('mike', 'A', 12), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a value that expresses the order you want it sorted in. The easiest way is with a tuple.

```
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda e: (e[2], e[1]))
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('mike', 'A', 12), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```